# How to sort the retrieved user data according to date and time in android firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am retrieving posts data from firebase database. The retrieved data includes my posts as well as the posts of the user i am following. Everything is going good, but i want to sort the retrieved data according to time and date that i have stored with every post. i have tried many solutions but i am unable to achieve my desire out put.

Here is my code:

```
    //For retrieving the detail of current user posts and setting it in custom listview through DataModel class
    com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener eventListener = new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                String description = ds.child("description").getValue(String.class);
                String dateTime = ds.child("dateTime").getValue(String.class);
                String posturi = ds.child("posturi").getValue(String.class);
                String severity = ds.child("severity").getValue(String.class);
                String lat = ds.child("lat").getValue(String.class);
                String lon = ds.child("lon").getValue(String.class);


                DataModel dataModel = new DataModel(userID, name, dateTime, description, profileImage, posturi, lon, lat, severity);
                list.add(dataModel);
            }

            adapter = new CustomAdapter(Home.this, list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("DataBase Error", databaseError.toString());
        }

    };
 databaseref_currentuser_post.orderByChild("dateTime").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

//retrieving the data of the user i am following.

```
databaseref_otheruser_post = databaseReference.child(id).child("posts");

databaseref_otheruser_post.orderByChild("dateTime").addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            for (com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                                String description = ds.child("description").getValue(String.class);
                                String dateTime = ds.child("dateTime").getValue(String.class);
                                String posturi = ds.child("posturi").getValue(String.class);
                                String severity = ds.child("severity").getValue(String.class);
                                String lat = ds.child("lat").getValue(String.class);
                                String lon = ds.child("lon").getValue(String.class);


                                DataModel dataModel1 = new DataModel(id, othername, dateTime, description, picture, posturi, lon, lat, severity);
                                list.add(dataModel1);
                            }
                            adapter = new CustomAdapter(Home.this, list);
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

[Here is my database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0iPL.png)

Thank in advance!

Comment: one suggestion whenever you store date to server always store `getTime()` long value it's easy to handle

Comment: Now your question you need to parse your string `dateTime` to java `Date` and then sort your  ArrayList

Comment: before setting list to adapter you need to sort your arraylist on date